# Speed Up Access 2010 Runtime

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've recently upgraded some access clients (proprietary app) to the 2010 run time and it is extremely slow.  The UI is running of MS-SQL Server with extremely low latencies.  The lag seems to come from the graphics on the front end.  For instance when you change tabs the CPU spikes to 50 or 75 percent on older PC's.

Does anyone know of any tricks to speed up the run-time ?

Comment: Is the front end shared and located on a shared drive location on a network that the users are directly connected to? Does each individual have their own front end located on their own PC with linked SQL server tables? Remotely accessing aacdb front end files through VPN could be extremely sluggish.

Comment: @Scotch No the Front end is installed on each PC and connects to central MSSQL DB.  No One is working over a VPN.  We had essentially the same app on access runtime 2003 and it was very fast.  It seems to me to be the bloat of the 2010 runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not have seen any real difference in performance. You I suppose turn off themes and see if rendering issues are causing this.

As a general rule the speed of VBA is the SAME in 2010 as previous versions (run some bench mark code).

Where you can find some slowdowns is code that references lots of text box properties on a form (the reason being the number of properties for a control is about 4 times what I was before – a printout of properties used to be about a page or so, now I believe is an around 6 pages of a printout JUST for a single text box and properties.  So code that does lots of changes to lots of control properties can often be suspect and will run slower.

However, general loading and display of forms has not been really any noticeable issue here. It not clear if you experiencing this for all forms or just some. Usually the culprit is poor code or too much data being pulled into the form, and not form rendering speed.

Make a copy of the form and then remove all data sources (including combo box data source). Try that form now, does it still load slowly without any data?

So general VBA code speed should not change much here. As noted, I would also try turning off themes. I also assume you distributing an accDE file here, as that can also help speed wise.

Comment: First thing I tried but it didn't help.  The code is third party so no good there